# List all subfolders of a folder that existed at some point in a branch of a Git repository

Tags: git

How can I list all subfolders of a specific folder that exist or have existed in at least one commit of a branch of a Git repository?

I don't want to manually go through a Git log of each commit, which would take lots of time for longer histories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only -- path/to/folder/ | sort | uniq
```

would list every subpath appearing in your commit history, sort it, and get rid of all doubles.

It would not output *only the subfolders* (but also the files inside that folder), but could it suit your needs?

Comment: It lists the paths of all files in and below the folder, still a quite long list but I can extract the subfolders from there. Thanks.